# Can't locate element in hybrid app after changing context to webview Python/Appium

Tags: python, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

```
import time

from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

desired_caps=dict(

    deviceName='Android',
    platformName='Android',
    appPackage= 'com.android.chrome',
    appActivity='org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity'

)
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get('http://google.com')

contexts= driver.contexts

for context in contexts:
    print(context)

driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW_chrome')

time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@name='q']").send_keys("Hello Appium !!!")

time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

I cant find element and execute script, i am getting same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@name='q']"}
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.136)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003FDCE3+50899]
    (No symbol) [0x0038E111]
    (No symbol) [0x00295588]
    (No symbol) [0x002C08F9]
    (No symbol) [0x002C0AFB]
    (No symbol) [0x002EF902]
    (No symbol) [0x002DB944]
    (No symbol) [0x002EE01C]
    (No symbol) [0x002DB6F6]
    (No symbol) [0x002B7708]
    (No symbol) [0x002B886D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00663EAE+2566302]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006992B1+2784417]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0069327C+2759788]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00495740+672048]
    (No symbol) [0x00398872]
    (No symbol) [0x003941C8]
    (No symbol) [0x003942AB]
    (No symbol) [0x003871B7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75AF0099+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77567B6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77567B3E+238]
```

At first i got chromedriver error, i corrected that, i checked the locators just in case, i tried 2 techniques to change context, i even tried to execute it in native app context, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do below changes to your code

1. Add some capabilities which will wait to load Webviews
2. Use `chromedriverExecutable` capability and provide chromeDriverExecutable path
3. While setting text on Text field do not implement sendKeys() directly on element. Store it in some variable and call sendKeys()

Here is the complete working code

```
desired_caps = dict(
    platformName='Android',
 chromedriverExecutable='C:/xxx/xx/xx/xx/chromedriver.exe',
    deviceName='Pixel 4 API 28',
    autoWebviewTimeout='10000',
    automationName="UiAutomator2",
    setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled=True,
    appPackage='com.android.chrome',
    appActivity='org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity',
)
print("Starting remote session")
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
print("waiting")
time.sleep(20)
print("opening google")
driver.get('http://google.com')
print("openeed google")
time.sleep(5)
print("getting contexts")
contexts = driver.contexts
for context in contexts:
    print(context)
print("switching contexts")
driver.switch_to.context("WEBVIEW_chrome")
time.sleep(10)
textField= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@name='q']")
textField.send_keys("Hello Appium !!!")
print("Set Text successfully")
driver.quit()
```

My emulator was too slow that is reason I have to add so many wait. As it is not good practice you can remove wherever not needed or you can use explicit wait[image]